# How adjust Android listview column width at runtime?

Tags: android, android-listview

Does the Android listview has a method to achieve this goal?

I would like to implement the function like listview in C# or vb. There users can adjust the 
column width by themselves.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can specifically set the width on a ListView element.  That kinda defeats the purpose of Android's layout system.  Similar to WPF, Android lays out its UI's in a fluid and dynamic way so that it can intelligently lay out all the children within a View based on their relationships.  That's why views are added to layout containers.  Maybe if you describe what it is you're trying to do, there might be a more Android-like solution than explicitly setting the width after the view has already been drawn or measured.

Here's a good link to read when thinking about Android layouts and views:

[How Android Draws Views](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html)